# Make a linux network device a router

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ipv6

I am developing an IPv6 network device driver. It should behaviors like a router, i.e. send router advertisement regularly. But now my device is working like a node, send router solicitation. What should I do to change it to a router? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Linux kernel does not know how to send router advertisements; it relies on a userspace daemon for that.  You'll want to install and configure `radvd`, the Router Advertisement Daemon.  http://tomicki.net/ipv6.router.php is a pretty good tutorial on what you need to do.

Setting the sysctl `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1` will disable the router solicitations (but will not produce router advertisements).  This setting is also necessary to run `radvd`.